# How to use $router.push in Vue-router?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, axios, vue-router

i need to use `$router.push` in Vue-router. Check my code:

```
axios.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {
    return response
  }, function (error) {
    if(error && error.message === 'Network Error'){
        //here is problem. I can;t use this.$router in js file? How to fix this?
        this.$router.push('calendar')
    }
    return Promise.reject(error)
  })
```

My question is how do I use `$router.push` in this file?  Check my router:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import Home from '../views/Home.vue'
import axios from 'axios'
Vue.use(VueRouter);

axios.interceptors.response.use(function(response) {
  return response
}, function(error) {
  if (error && error.message === 'Network Error') {
    Vue.push('home')
  }
  return Promise.reject(error)
})

const routes = [{
  path: '/',
  name: 'home',
  component: Home
}, {
  other routes
}]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with route [navigation guards](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#global-after-hooks).

Here's a contrived example using `beforeEach` (runs before every route):

```js
router.beforeEach(async (to, from, next) => {
  const response = await axios.get(...);
  if (response.data.isGood) {
    next();
  } else {
    next({ name: 'home' });
  }
});
```

This would run an async call before navigating to each route, and then check the response data.  If everything is good, the navigation proceeds.  Otherwise, the user is redirected back to the home route.

You can do this for individual routes with `beforeEnter`:

```js
{
    path: '/',
    name: 'home',
    component: Home,
    async beforeEnter(to, from, next) {
      // same axios call & next usage as above example
    }
}
```

Comment: Did this answer solve your problem? Please checkmark this answer and this will help other people as well. You can do so [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpogP.png).  Or let me know if anything is unclear.